# Why do I get 0 every time i call the array from a class?

Tags: java, arrays, class

Here is what i'm supposed to do:

> Write a class with a constructor that accepts a file names as its argument.
>   Assume the file constain a series of numbers, each written on a separate line. The class should read the contents of the file file into an array, and then displays the following date:
>
> - The lowest number in the array
> - The highest number in the array
> - The total of the numbers in the array
> - The average of the numbers in the array
> - The content of the array.

every time I run  the program I get the amount of numbers in the array, as 0 and the other outputs as well.

here is the worker `NumberAnalisis` class:

```
package chapter7;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberAnalisis {

    private int[] array;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @throws IOException 
     */

    public NumberAnalisis(String name) throws IOException{

        File file = new File(name);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        int count =0;   //To count the amount of numbers 
                       //in the file.

        int index = 0;  //Index for an array.

        int number;

        //Determine the amount of numbers in a file.
        while(inputFile.hasNext()){
            inputFile.nextInt();
            count++;
        }

        //Create an array as big as the amount of numbers 
        //in the file.
        array = new int[count];

        //Store the content of the file into the array.
        while(inputFile.hasNext() && index<array.length){
            number = inputFile.nextInt();
            array[index] = number;
            index++;
        }
        inputFile.close();  //Close the file.
    }

    /**
     * The getHigh method 
     * @return the highest number
     * in the file.
     */

    public int getHigh(){

        int high;

        high = array[0];

        for(int index =1; index<array.length; index++){
            if(array[index]>high){
                high = array[index];
            }
        }

        return high;
    }

    /**
     * The getLow method
     * @return The lowest number
     * in the file.
     */

    public int getLow(){
        int low;

        low = array[0];

        for(int index =1; index<array.length; index++){

            if(array[index]<low){
                low = array[index];
            }
        }

        return low;
    }


    /**
     * The total method
     * @return return the
     * total in the file.
     */

    public int total(){
        int total =0;

        for(int index =0; index<array.length; index++){
            total += array[index];
        }
        return total;
    }

    /**
     * The average method
     * @return The average
     * of the numbers in 
     * the file.
     */

    public double average(){

        double average =0;

        for(int index =0; index<array.length; index++){
            average += array[index];
        }

        return average/array.length;
    }

    /**
     * The getFile method 
     * @return the content 
     * of the file.
     */

    public int[] getFile(){
        return array;
    }
}//End of class.
```

Here is the `main` class:

```
package chapter7;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberAnalisisTest {

    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException{
        String name;

         name = createFile();
         display(name);

    }//End of main.

    /**
     * The createFile method prompt the user
     * to create a file and store numbers.
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public static String createFile()throws IOException{

        String name;    //Name to hold the file.

        int numbers =0; //To hold the number going into 
                     //the file.

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the name to create a file");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Create a file.
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(name + ".txt");

        System.out.println("Let's start adding numbers to the file\n");

        //Store numbers into the file.
        while(!(numbers==-1)){
            System.out.println("Enter a number" + "\nto quit press -1");
            numbers = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(!(numbers==-1)){
                outputFile.println(numbers);
            }
        }
        outputFile.close();
        keyboard.close();
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * The display method displays
     * content of the file,
     * the lowest number in the file
     * the highest, the total and the
     * average.
     * @throws IOException 
     */

    public static void display(String fileName) throws IOException{

        NumberAnalisis  number = new NumberAnalisis(fileName + ".txt");

        System.out.println("The content of the file is the following");

        //Display the content of the file.
        for(int index = 0; index<number.getFile().length; index++){
            System.out.println(number.getFile()[index]);
        }

        System.out.println("The highest number in the file is " 
                        + number.getHigh() + "\nThe Lowest is "
                        + number.getLow() + "\nThe average is "
                        + number.average());
    }
}//End of class.
```

Comment: The problem is that you're reading everything in the file to determine how many items there are, and then not re-opening the file to actually get the data.

Comment: I suggest you learn some debugging skills. These are as important as knowing how to write code.

Comment: The loop after the `Determine the amount of numbers in a file` comment will read all the numbers in the file, i.e. until `inputFile.hasNext()` returns false. The next loop after `Store the content of the file into the array` will try to **continue** reading as long as `inputFile.hasNext()` returns true, and will find nothing, since you're already at the end of the file (`hasNext()` is *still* false). Solution: Don't read twice. Just loop once and insert into an `ArrayList`, which will auto-size as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy. You count amount of integers in file correctly. Initialize the array with correct length. By default array elements are 0s. Now when there is no number to read, for each number to read you change array values. It results with no changes so the array stays filled with 0s.

The solution will be the following:

```
    File file = new File(name);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    int count =0;   //To count the amount of numbers 
                   //in the file.

    int index = 0;  //Index for an array.

    int number;

    //Determine the amount of numbers in a file.
    while(inputFile.hasNext()){
        inputFile.nextInt();
        count++;
    }

    //Create an array as big as the amount of numbers 
    //in the file.
    array = new int[count];
    inputFile.close();
    inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    //Store the content of the file into the array.
    while(inputFile.hasNext() && index<array.length){
        number = inputFile.nextInt();
        array[index] = number;
        index++;
    }
    inputFile.close();  //Close the file.
```

Comment: The answer is pretty easy: Use a `List`.

Comment: Yes, the list would be a good approach. Let the OP write something on his/her own

Answer (score 3):

```
   //Determine the amount of numbers in a file.
    while(inputFile.hasNext()){
        inputFile.nextInt();
        count++;
    }

    //Create an array as big as the amount of numbers 
    //in the file.
    array = new int[count];

    //Store the content of the file into the array.
    while(inputFile.hasNext() && index<array.length){
        number = inputFile.nextInt();
        array[index] = number;
        index++;
    }
    inputFile.close();  //Close the file.
```

You don't reset the file in any way between these two. So, `inputFile.hasNext()` returns false on the very first iteration of the second while loop, so that never gets run, so you never initialize any of the elements of your array (and they default to zero).

Answer (score 1):

You've iterated over Scanner in NumberAnalisis wher calculated size of the array. You have to reset counter because inputFile.hasNext() in your second loop returns false

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm

And use step-by-step debuging, you'll see for yourself when values go aout of hand

Comment: Of course there is no need to reset the counter! The pointer in file should be reseted

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you read the file all the way through to count the number of things it has, then you start reading the things without rewinding the file. You need to close and re-open or reset the file pointer to the beginning before the second read loop.

Comment: You can't reset a `Scanner` back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: @nicomp reset method on Scanner doesn't move the pointer in the file.

Comment: I didn't write anything about resetting a Scanner object. Please go back and study my answer.